# separate the size of array and array value by delimiter -1 in c++

Tags: c++, delimiter

> Separate the size of array and array value by delimiter -1
>
> Input is of the form:
>
> ```
> Array-size -1 array-values(separated by ,) -1 number -1
> 3 -1 3,5,7 -1 6 -1
> ```
>
> Don't use vector, take the values into array of size given by user otherwise print "-1".

I have tried this code but I am not able to complete it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
    
using namespace std;
    
int main(){
    string s{};
    getline(cin, s)
    stringstream ss(s);

    string count = size_t{};
    string delimiter1 = string{};
    string value = string{};
    string delimiter2 = string{};
    string size = string{};
    string delimiter3 = string{};

    if(!(ss >> count >> delimiter1 >> values >> delimiter2 >> size >> delimiter2))
        cout << -1 << endl;

    if(delimiter1 != "-1" || delimiter2 != "-1" || delimiter3 != "-1")
        cout << -1 << endl;

    int a[1000];

    while(getline(ss, value, ',')){
        a.push_back(stoi(value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why "_Don't use vector_"? Storing the values in a `std::vector` would seem perfect for this.

Comment: What is your actual question? You do know that plain ordinary C-style arrays don’t have a `push_back` method, don’t you?

Comment: @Jessica that is not a question, that is merely stating a requirement. What is your QUESTION? This is a Q&A site. We are here to answer questions.

Comment: @Jessica Can you tell us more - what are you supposed to do after storing the array (expected output)? What is the role of that number at the end (`6` in your example)?

Comment: Ok, are you allowed to use `std::unique_ptr`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't seem a million miles away, but you haven't decalred `values`, and you have initalised `ss` in the wrong place, and used `delimiter2` where you meant `delimiter3`, and you tried to use `push_back` on an array.

Other errors are reading integers values as strings, which seems to be making more work for yourself.

Finally since you know how many integers you have to read, you should probably use that information.

This code looks to be closer

```
int main() {
    // read line of data
    string s;
    getline(cin, s)

    // initial parse of data
    size_t count, size;
    int delimiter1, delimiter2, delimiter3;
    string values;
    if (!(ss >> count >> delimiter1 >> values >> delimiter2 >> size >> delimiter3))
        std::cerr << "error here\n";

    // check delimiters
    if (delimiter1 != -1 || delimiter2 != -1 || delimiter3 != -1)
        std::cerr << "error here\n";

    // read count integers into array
    int a[1000];
    stringstream ss(values);
    string value;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
         if (!getline(ss, value, ',')) {
             std::cerr << "error here\n";
         }
         a[i] = stoi(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more I am stuck here and not able write further code, how to take input as specified in the form "Array-size -1 array-values(separated by ,) -1 number -1" and store values into array 'a' .

Comment: @Jessica I've updated the code, what isn't clear about it?

Comment: Please explain the magic number "1000". Is there reason to assume that a larger array will never be required? Other than "OP makes the same unfounded assumption." I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this much code will be fine. It will print `-1` on `stderr` if input format is malformed or if `n` is very large.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  try {
    int n, _, number;
    std::string str;
    std::cin.exceptions(std::istream::failbit);
    std::cin >> n >> _;
    int *arr = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0, temp; i < n; ++i) {
      std::cin >> temp;
      arr[i] = temp;
      std::cin >> std::ws;
      std::cin.ignore();
    }
    std::cin >> _ >> number >> _;
    // do something with array and number
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n' << number;
  } catch (...) {
    std::cerr << -1;
  }
}
```

Sample Run : https://wandbox.org/permlink/hfcXf4BTXQSwCiVm